# How to consume a spring data rest service with java?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data

I have the following spring boot + data Rest repository:

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "dto", path = "produtos")
    public interface ProdutoRepository extends CrudRepository<Produto, Integer> {
        @Query("SELECT p FROM Produto p where descricao LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(:like),'%')")
        List<Produto> findByLike(@Param("like") String like);
    }
```

I also have a java client that access this method (this is my example of doing it):

```
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/produtos/search/findByLike?like={like}";
    RestTemplate t = new RestTemplate();
    ProdutoDto resp = t.getForObject(url, ProdutoDto.class, txtLoc.getText());
```

ProdutoDto (this one is not totally necessary):

```
public class ProdutoDto extends HalDto<Produto> {}
```

HalDto:

```
public class HalDto<T extends ResourceSupport> extends ResourceSupport {
    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    private EmbeddedDto<T> embedded;

    public EmbeddedDto<T> getEmbedded() {
        return embedded;
    }

    public void setEmbedded(EmbeddedDto<T> embedded) {
        this.embedded = embedded;
    }
}
```

EmbeddedDto:

```
public class EmbeddedDto<T> {
    @JsonProperty("dto")
    private List<T> dtoList;

    public List<T> getDtoList()
    {
        return dtoList;
    }

    public void setDto(List<T> dtoList) {
        this.dtoList = dtoList;
    }
}
```

Those classes are necessary (i think) because Spring Data returns data in the HAL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language) format.

Note: Produto must extend ResourceSupport.

Caveats: All collectionResourceRel must be named "dto" and it only works for collections (may be adjusted).

Is this the proper way to do this?

I have googled around and found plenty of examples of doing the server side, but almost nothing on building clients.

Thanks.

Comment: *Is this the proper way to do this?*: what happens when you run your code? Does it do what you want it to do? That should answer your question.

Comment: It works, but I am not sure if it's the right way (knowing that "right" is relative). We will be doing a lot o coding with spring boot + data, so doing it right is important.

Comment: Did you come up with a proper way? I'm facing the same issue atm as I'm writing unit tests. @JBNizet I think the question here is if Spring already provides a generic abstract class that we can simply extend and let Spring - once again - do its magic tricks.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I just disabled It and wrote my own data api.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that I have found which seems to work well.

First, setup your `RestTemplate` so that it expects JSON/HAL and knows what to do with it:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter =
                    new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        messageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
        return new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(messageConverter));

}
```

Then you can use the `exchange` method of the `RestTemplate` to specify that you want your result to be `ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Producto>>`

```
ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Producto>> resultResponse = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Producto>>(){});

if(resultResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
    Collection<Producto> results = resultResponse.getBody().getContent();
    log.info("{} results obtained", results.size());
}
```

You can instantiate `restTemplate` by either calling the `restTemplate()` method defined above or you can inject (autowire) it.